# GatsbyJs: Using Markdown and style checkboxes

Tags: css, markdown, gatsby

I am using the gatsby-docs-starter and write all my files in markdown.

To style some checkboxes i use

```
- [x] || [ ] some text
```

Is there a way to style them properly?

I can make them disappear but I cant style them, as I can assign some class to them.

they always render as

```
<input type="checkbox" checked disabled/>
```

I want to use only Markdown and CSS for this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Markdown itself doesn't have a way to define a class to your input, unless you wanted to write them in html inside the markdown file.

To style them you could write a rule that is dependent on their parent wrapper. For example, add a class to any parent and then target via `.parentClass input { ... }`. Or, depending on the nature of checkboxes elsewhere on the site, target via the type selector `input[type=checkbox] { ... }`

Comment: Can you please explain more on how to add the class you mentioned? Thank you!